# How to find minimum value in ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs

Hi i'm trying to get the minimum price in my repeater. I'll add a green sign near to this list item. (as you see in code, "span class min-value")

How can I get this minimum value and use my span as "ng-show" in my html?

Thank you.

```js
var app = angular.module("App", []);

app.controller("Controller", function($scope) {
  $scope.priceList = [{
    "name": "Product 1",
    "price": "100"
  }, {
    "name": "Product 2",
    "price": "200"
  }, {
    "name": "Product 3",
    "price": "300"
  }, {
    "name": "Product 4",
    "price": "400"
  }, {
    "name": "Product 5",
    "price": "500"
  }];
});
```

```css
li {
  padding: 10px;
}
.min-price {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: green;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>
<html lang="en" ng-app="App">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body ng-controller="Controller">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in priceList">
      {{item.name}} - {{item.price}}$
      <span class="min-price" ng-show="true"></span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: In the js file loop through the array and find the biggest or smallest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is simple logic for you:-

```
<span class="min-price" ng-show="isMin(item.price)"></span>

$scope.isMin=function(price){
    var min=$scope.priceList[0].price;

   for(var i=0;i<= $scope.priceList.length-1;i++){

     if(Number($scope.priceList[i].price) < min){
       min=$scope.priceList[i].price;
       console.log("Min"+min);
     }
   }
   console.log("min:"+min+ " price:"+price);
    if(min===price){
      return true;
    }else{
      return false;
    }
  }
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/mfv5ZAVhdSL7zY9dZUkS?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

Compute the minimum price in the controller, using JavaScript code, and store the result in a scope variable (`minimumPrice` for example).

Then use

```
ng-show="item.price == minimumPrice"
```

Hint: don't use strings to represent numbers. Use numbers.

Comment: or use parseInt()